# Unable to locate and click a button into Angular 7 app using Selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this Angular 7 application into which I want to click a login button:

```
<button _ngcontent-klg-c2="" cdkfocusinitial="" color="primary" fxflex="100px" id="login" mat-button="" mat-flat-button="" class="mat-button mat-flat-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" style="flex: 1 1 100px; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100px; min-width: 100px;"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Login</span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

I tried to click the button using:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("login"))).click();


org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-ghy-c2="" cdkfocusinitial="" color="primary" fxflex="100px" id="login" mat-button="" mat-flat-button="" class="mat-button mat-flat-button mat-primary ng-star-inserted" style="flex: 1 1 100px; box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">...</button> is not clickable at point (846, 858). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-ghy-c1="" class="ngx-overlay foreground-closing" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); border-radius: 0px;">...</div>
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=86.0.622.63)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: It is possible that the immediate parent element is receiving this click or there could be other elements with same "login" id. can you share the complete page source around the button element.

Comment: No, this id="login" is unique.

Comment: Is the button element changing - before and after click manually ? try sending the click to the focus overlay element. either - class = 'mat-button-focus-overlay' or class = 'ngx-overlay foreground-closing' .

Comment: Which locator should I use?

Comment: By.xpath("//button/div[@class='mat-button-focus-overlay']") or By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-overlay foreground-closing']")